# VBA GetOpenFileName error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which uses GetOpenFileName() to get an excel file from user.

```
Sub openFile()

Dim wb As Workbook, wbName As Variant

wbName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")

If wbName <> False Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbName)
End If

wb.Close False

End Sub
```

The problem is that after macro runs I can't move or rename the folder that contains the chosen file. I can rename the file but not the folder unless I close the worbook with the macro.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you have opened a file in a folder, Excel will have placed a "lock" on the folder.  It will release the lock when you close Excel, or open a file in some other folder.  (Actually, it is probably the `GetOpenFilename`, not the `Open`, that is "locking" the folder.)

Comment: @YowE3K I agree but I don't think the `GetOpenFilename` would lock it as the documentation states `Displays the standard Open dialog box and gets a file name from the user without actually opening any files.`

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K, but is there a way to realease the lock without reopening the workbook?

Comment: The documentation also warns "This method may change the current drive or folder."

Comment: @YowE3K touche!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetOpenFilename` changes the "current" directory to the one specified in the dialog.

It's impossible to change the name of, or delete, the directory which is currently the "current" directory of the Excel application object.

Try the following fix:

```
Sub openFile()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbName As Variant

    wbName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")

    If wbName <> False Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbName)
        wb.Close False
    End If

    'Change "current" directory
    ChDrive "C"
    ChDir "C:\"

End Sub
```